# Helicopter shot in Cricket

Tags: cricket, trivia, history

I wondering, who introduced the helicopter shot in cricket. MS Dhoni used to play that shot very often. If I remember correctly Sri Lankan opener Marvan Atapattu use to play similar kind of shots in his own style.

Does anybody knows who introduced that shot to the cricket world?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [Page](http://www.sportskeeda.com/slideshow/5-players-attempted-helicopter-shot-cricket) says , [Abdul Razzaq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdul_Razzaq_(cricketer)) was the first player to try a helicopter shot.

But there is a similar [quora question](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-first-batsman-ever-to-play-the-famous-helicopter-shot), it says [Mohammad Azharuddin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Azharuddin)
 and [Ajay Jadeja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajay_Jadeja) have tried helicopter shots back in 1996(youtube links are attached in that page, but I am unable to open it).

There might be a lot of players who have played similar kind of shots in the past.

But the name Helicopter was introduced in 2011 when [Dhoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahendra_Singh_Dhoni) featured in a Pepsi advertisement.

**I would say [Dhoni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahendra_Singh_Dhoni) was the only player who have used the shot to it's potential.**